# If $a\neq b \mod 2$, then why $a − b ≡ b \mod 2$?why do we have $(a + bi) − 1 = 0 $ in the quotient field?.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that the quotient ring $\frac{\mathbb{Z[i]}}{(1+i)}$ is  a field of order $2$

My  attempt  : I found the answer  [here](http://www.math.caltech.edu/%7E2016-17/2term/ma005b/solutions/hw4%20solutions.pdf) see page no $1$

It is written that

> By computing the norm we know $1+i$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z[i]}$, so $\mathbb{Z[i]}/(1+i)$ is indeed a field.
> Any element in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has the form $a+bi$ for some $a, b \in\mathbb{ Z}$. If $a ≡ b \mod 2$, then $(1+i)( (a+b)/2 +
> (b−a)i/2) =a + bi$, so $a + bi = 0$ in the quotient field.**If $a\neq b \mod 2$, then $a − b ≡ b \mod 2$, in which case by
> a similar computation we have $(a + bi) − 1 = 0 $in the quotient field**. Thus the only elements in the
> quotient field is $0$ and $1$, so we obtain a finite field of order $2.$

**My confusion** :Im not getting this  statement

> If $a\neq b \mod 2$, then $a − b ≡ b \mod 2$, in which case by
> a similar computation we have $(a + bi) − 1 = 0 $in the quotient field.

**First confusion** :If $a\neq b \mod 2$, then  why  $a − b ≡ b \mod 2$?

**2nd confusion**:why do we have $(a + bi) − 1 = 0 $ in the quotient field?.

**My thinking**  :If $a ≡ b \mod 2$,then $a+b$  and $b-a $  are even $\implies   a+bi \in (1+i)$

The elements of $\mathbf{Z}[i]/(1 + i)$ are the cosets of $(1 + i)$ and they are respectively $(1 + i)$ and $1 + (1 + i)$.  Take an element $a + bi \in \mathbf{Z}[i]$. By the division theorem, we can write $a + bi = q(1 + i) + r$ with $N(r) < N(1 + i) = 2$. That is $r = 0, 1$ . Hence the cosets are $0 + (1 + i)$, $1 + (1 + i)$

Therefore every element  of  $\mathbb{Z}[i] $ is in either $(1+i)$  or $1+ (1+i)$   so $\frac{{Z}[i]}{(1+i)}$  is  a  finite  ring of order  $2$,which must be  a field

Comment: By the linked dupe, in $\Bbb Z[x]/(1+i)\,$ we have $i=-1\,$ so $\,0=(1+i)(1-i)=2\,$ so $\,a+bi = (a-b)\bmod 2\ \ $

Comment: $a\not\equiv b$ mod $2$ does not imply $a-b\equiv b$ mod $2$. It must be a typo for $a-1\equiv b$ mod $2$.

Comment: okay @runway44  Yes..I think you are right